# WMI Access denied issue

Tags: c#, wmi

I am using C# & WMI to retrieve REMOTE COMPUTER services. The connection is made using ConnectionOptions with username & password. Username has administrative privilege. I can query Win32_OperatingSystem OR Win32_LogicalDisk without any problem. But when I query SELECT * FROM Win32_Service then I get Access Denied issue. I give permission to the user from CIMV2 namespace for remoteEnable, DCOM permission for Remote Access, Remote Lunch, Remote Activation. But still having that issue.
Can anyone tell what else need to do?

Comment: Please don't repeat tags like "C#" in the title. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add code to specify impersonationLevel=impersontate otherwise WMI doesn't raise the security level of the creds - even if they're explicit.